# Create Javascript to add div tag before iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I add a `<div>` tag before `<iframe>` loads, using javascript? For example:

```
<div><iframe>Text</iframe></div>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or any js DOM tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have jQuery and not going for pure js.

```
$('iframe').wrap('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('iframe').contents().bind('load', function () {
    $('iframe').appendTo('div');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, and the following is your HTML...

```
<main id="content"><iframe>Text</iframe></main>
```

... then you could use ...

```
$('iframe').wrap( "<div></div>");
```

... or ...

```
$( "iframe" ).wrapAll( "<div></div>");
```

... or ...

```
$('#content').wrapInner( "<div></div>");
```

... to turn it into ...

```
<main id="content"><div><iframe>Text</iframe></div></main>
```

Each of these three statements do pretty much the same thing in this specific context.

---

#### Documentation :

- [**.wrap()**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)
- [**.wrapAll()**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)
- [**.wrapInner()**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)